# Low bandwidth tools

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components

Does anyone know a good mechanism for measuring or reporting on page sizes?

I have a low bandwidth (humanitarian client) use case and trying to evaluate my pages, hi-res imagery or other page size issues, across the org. As an example, even a standard Lightning page view seems to be coming in at around 700kb, which seems high.

If there’s something on the AppEchange that would be great, but otherwise any direction in reporting, API tools or creating this through other mechanisms would be really helpful.

I have searched the Salesforce AppExchange, and available metadata/other API and so far haven't found anything. Event Monitoring has logs that help general page load performance and I found an article around improving performance, but haven't found ways to identify SIZE as would be needed for low bandwidth scenarios.

Don't know where to start yet, unfortunately. This could be a programmatic solution, in which case I'd love some direction, but it could also be tools available elsewhere I'm not aware of.